# Is it possible for a graph to have more k-cliques rather than (k-1)-cliques?

Tags: graph-theory

Given undirected graphs $G=(v,e)$, I am counting cliques of different sizes denoted as $k$.

I am doing this automatically through a script and I spotted a behaviour that I am not sure can be true. I am also unable to check manually due to the large graphs.

When I try to count cliques of size $k$ and $k-1$ (e.g., 4-cliques and 3-cliques) I get a larger set of size $k-1$ rather than $k$. Intuitively, I don't think this is true.

P.S. I am new to graph theory.

Comment: Why not? For example, eventually the graph will have zero $k$-cliques and one step before that some nonzero number of $(k-1)$-cliques. Actually the most "intuitive" thing to expect would be that the sequence of clique numbers is unimodal - first it grows to some point and then decreases. This is a topic of a number of (hard) conjectures for various classes of graphs.

Answer (score 1):

In the complete graph $K_n$ the number of $k$-cliques is $\binom nk$ and the number of $(k-1)$-cliques is $\binom n{k-1}$.

$\binom n{k-1}\gt\binom nk$ if $k-1\le n\le2k-2$.

$\binom nk\gt\binom n{k-1}$ if $n\ge2k$.